# git push from forked to new branch

Tags: git

i have forked a repository, simply because i don't like that the repository is not in my "repositiries" list.

and i now wish to push my changes into the original repository, but to a new branch called analytics.

anyway:
this code works to push into the main branch.

```
git fetch upstream
git push upstream main
```

but if i try something like this:

```
git fetch upstream
git push upstream analytics
```

it fails with the following error:

```
error: src refspec analytics does not match any
```

if i print the branches i see:

```
> git branch -v -a
* main                       95c8c55 next
  remotes/origin/HEAD        -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main        95c8c55 next
  remotes/upstream/Shani     e7b39cd Add files via upload
  remotes/upstream/analytics ddaeaa5 test brach
  remotes/upstream/main      ddaeaa5 test brach
```

how do i push into the analytics branch and not straigh into main branch?

another question is maybe i should just use the original repository and not fork at all, so is that even a good idea what iam trying to do?

Comment: To push local `main` to remote `analytics` branch you would say `git push upstream main:analytics`. But is that really what you want to do, and have you the rights to do it?

Comment: yeah it might sound silly but i can commit directly to the original repository.
might be really silly to fork then hmm....

the only reason i made the fork was so the repository would be visible from my repositories.

also you'r solution works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a local branch `analytics`, before pushing it to `upstream`:

```
git switch -c analytics
git push upstream analytics
```

However, that would not work considering you cannot directly push back to upstream: you had, after all, to fork upstream in the first place.

It is best to push it to `origin`, and make a PR from origin to `upstream`.
You can create a PR directly from your local clone, using [`gh pr create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_create).

> I can commit directly to the original repository.
> might be really silly to fork then hmm.... the only reason I made the fork was so the repository would be visible from my repositories.

In that case, the first push I mention would work.
The idea remains: don't work on `main` directly, work in a dedicated branch. Hence the first switch, to create said branch from your current work (done at first on `main`)
And `git branch -f main origin/main`, to reset `main` to its original value.

Comment: But none of this grapples with the fact that the OP apparently created commits on main.

Comment: The first switch creates a branch from the local main, precisely to include those commits.

Comment: But apparently too late. The commits are already created, so `analytics` would be just another name for `main` at this point.

Comment: @matt No matter: what is pushed is the right branch (analytics) with the right commits. (initially created on main) You can still reset `main` to `origin/main`.

Comment: Yes, but what I'm saying is that we need to tell the OP that. The commits seems to have been created directly on main, and the OP seems to believe that that's just fine.

Comment: the commits are on main on a forked repository,
i.e i just wanted a different clone of that repository that i will work on,
and then push to my own branch on the original.

Comment: @MtkelN Exactly. The answer works for what you described.